# Weak and dominant energy conditions

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I'm trying to understand why it is that the physical quantities $\rho=T_{\mu \nu}a^{\mu}a^{\nu}$ and $b^{\mu}=T^{\mu}_{\:\: \nu}a^{\nu}$ can be given the physical interpretation that they have which are: 
if $a^{\mu}$ is timelike then (1) $\rho$ is the total mass energy density (2) $b^{\mu}$ is the momentum (both measured by observers on the geodesics that define $a^{\mu}$) . Here is a link to wiki with a more in depth definition if needed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_condition#Mathematical_statement.

If the stress-energy tensor is that of a perfect fluid, I think it's quite easy to see these physical interpretations are true but I have very little intuition about what any other stress-energy tensors are like.

Comment: To clarify: Are you already comfortable with the interpretation of $T_{\mu 0}$ as the energy density for $\mu=0$ and as the momentum density for $\mu\neq 0$? I mean, is the question about how those ideas generalize to arbitrary timelike $a^\mu$, or is the question about how to justify those ideas even when $a^\mu=(1,0,0,0)$ (when it's something other than a perfect fluid)?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly ah yes, I totally forgot about the general definition and that we can just pick the a =(1,0,0,0). Thanks!